# PyQt QTreeView Disable child selection when parent selected

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

Does anyone know how one can disable a child from being selected once its corresponding parent is already selected and vice versa. Consider the following example:

A-1
 -2

where A is a parent node in the treeview and 1 and 2 are two children under that parent. If the user selects A he/she should not be able to select either 1 or 2. In the same way if the user selects either 1 or 2 he/she should not be able to select A.

Here is the code I have used. This class defines the TreeView model:

```
class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

'''
This class handles the treeview model.
'''

def __init__(self, top, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TreeModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__top = top

def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    if parent.isValid():
        parent_node = parent.internalPointer()
        node = parent_node.children[row]
        index = self.createIndex(row, column, node)
    else:
        index = self.createIndex(row, column, self.__top)
    return index

def parent(self, index):
    if index.isValid():
        node = index.internalPointer()
        parent = node.parent
        if parent is None:
            parent_index = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            parent_index = self.createIndex(parent.row(), 0, parent)
    else:
        parent_index = QtCore.QModelIndex()
    return parent_index

def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    node = index.internalPointer()
    if node is None:
        count = 1
    else:
        count = len(node.children)
    return count

def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    return 1

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        node = index.internalPointer()
        data = str(node.number)
    else:
        data = None
    return data

def addChild(self, index, child):
    self.beginInsertRows(index, self.rowCount(index), self.rowCount(index) + 1)
    parent = index.internalPointer()
    parent.addChild(child)
    self.endInsertRows()
    self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

This function adds nodes to the tree based on user input:

```
    for key, value in treeViewModelDict.items():
        temp = [key, value]
        treeViewDictList.append(temp)
    print(self.treedict)

    def recurse(parent, children_data):
        for child_data in children_data:
            if isinstance(child_data, list):
                recurse(child, child_data)
            else:
                child = MyData(child_data, parent=parent)
    top = MyData("Tree View of Selected Meters")
    for i, next in enumerate(treeViewDictList):
        recurse(top, next)
    self.model = TreeModel(top)
    self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
    self.treeView.expandAll()
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Please post the code for your model and node classes.

Comment: @TimWakeham Please see the edited post above

Answer (score 0):

You need to record somewhere what the current selection is.  I normally store that in the model somewhere.  The `selectionChanged` signal on the tree view's selection model is good for this.

Then give your model a flags method (it should really have this already) which checks if the current node's parent is selected, if it isn't then you return whatever flags you want or'd with `Qt.ItemIsSelectable`, if it is, return flags without `Qt.ItemIsSelectable`